# Software for exploring large set of textual data

Tags: corpora, software, analysis

I am working with large amounts of text and already have a bunch of programmatic instruments to explore them (Python, R, etc).

To say the truth, most of the exploration tasks like bigram extraction, collocations, context sampling are rather standard and I would like to use more handy tool to do the preliminary analysis.

Is there fast and smart tools to explore text corpora? Tried *AntConc*, but it seems rather slow and not much user-friendly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about software recommendations. Try [softwarerecs.se] instead.

Comment: @jknappen With all respect to the community rules, I don't think we should be too formal about it. SoftwareRecs are not meant for the very domain-specific application I am asking for. More to say, I doubt I can get any reasonable piece of advice there.

Comment: Are you looking specifically for a tool to prform some analysis task (then, which analysis task exactly?) or a browser-like interface where you can surf and search just to see what's in the corpus?

Answer (score 1):

AntConc won't ever be comparable to professional tools like Python or R. And it's not possible to know what the software is doing, or to adapt it, since it's not open source (it's freeware, I believe).

You could also create some GUIs on the top of Python packages like nltk and have the functions that you use at hand.

Answer (score 1):

AntConc 4 is designed to be much faster than AntConc 3 and should be a little more user friendly. It should be sufficienct for most core corpus tasks, but for more advanced studies, you might consider other tools or go into programming.